# Как работать с git worktree в phpstorm и видеть результат в браузере?

Tags: git, phpstorm, apache2

Есть простой проект `/var/www/testy.local` с одним файлом `index.php` с содержимым: `<?php echo 111;`.

Настройки апача стандартные:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName testy.local
   DocumentRoot /var/www/testy.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Итог: в браузере по адресу `http://testy.local` я вижу результат: 111

---

- Делаю две ветки `git branch b1`, `git branch b2`
- Делаю два worktree: `git worktree add worktree/b1 b1`, `git worktree add worktree/b2 b2`
- В каждом из них вношу изменения в `index.php`

**Вопрос 1:** как теперь в браузере посмотреть результат правок в каждом из worktree? Ведь апач указывает именно на корень диерктории, а не на переключенный worktree.

**Вопрос 2:** как работать с worktree в *PHPStorm* ? Как переключаться между worktree, чтобы можно было видеть изменённые файлы на вкладке "Commit"? Что сделать, чтобы ветка отображалась `b1`, а не `master` и чтобы мои коммиты можно было делать в ветку, на которую сейчас указывает worktree? Вручную в терминале писать `cd worktree/b1`, `git commit` меня **не устраивает**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]